# Terrain drawing over itself at larger sizes

Tags: c++, directx-11, terrain

I have had a terrain generation algorithm for a while and have had a lot of success with it. However when I decided to start work on Level of Detail (Has not been implemented), I started to notice that my terrain would begin to draw underneath itself as it got larger (when it gets to around 257 by 257). I'm not too sure why it starts to do this however I have a feeling its either due to me converting the 2d vector into a 1d or when i generate my indices but i am not 100 percent. If someone could have a look that would be amazing

[Terrain at 100 by 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeXL7.png)

[Terrain at 1000 by 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRT7I.png)

**Code used to Generate Vertices**

```
void TerrainObject::LoadFlatTerrain()
{

    float F_terrainDimentions = terrainDimentions; //used to stop integer division

    m_vertexCount = terrainDimentions * terrainDimentions; //terrainDimentions = the width and depth of the terrain

    float halfWidth = 0.5f * F_terrainDimentions;
    float halfDepth = 0.5f * F_terrainDimentions;

    // project the grid into xz plane 
    float dx = F_terrainDimentions / (F_terrainDimentions - 1);
    float dz = F_terrainDimentions / (F_terrainDimentions - 1);

    float du = 1.0f / (F_terrainDimentions - 1); // texture co-ordinates
    float dv = 1.0f / (F_terrainDimentions - 1);



//Resizes Vectors for Vertices

    vertices.resize(m_vertexCount);
    verts2d.resize(terrainDimentions);
    for (int i = 0; i < verts2d.size(); i++)
    {
        verts2d[i].resize(terrainDimentions);
    }


//Generates Vertices for 2d array
    for (int i = 0; i < terrainDimentions; i++)
    {
        float z = halfDepth - i * dz;

        for (int j = 0; j < terrainDimentions; j++)
        {
            float x = -halfWidth + j * dx;
            float y = 0;

            verts2d[i][j].Position.x = x;
            verts2d[i][j].Position.y = y;
            verts2d[i][j].Position.z = z;

            verts2d[i][j].Normal = XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            verts2d[i][j].Tangent = XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

            verts2d[i][j].TexCoord.x = j * du;
            verts2d[i][j].TexCoord.y = i * dv;

        }
    }

    //Converts to 1d array
    for (int i = 0; i < terrainDimentions; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < terrainDimentions; j++)
        {
            vertices[i * terrainDimentions + j].Position = verts2d[i][j].Position;
            vertices[i * terrainDimentions + j].TexCoord = verts2d[i][j].TexCoord;
            vertices[i * terrainDimentions + j].Normal = verts2d[i][j].Normal;
            vertices[i * terrainDimentions + j].Tangent = verts2d[i][j].Tangent;

        }

    }

    // Create vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbd;
    vbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    vbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(ComplexVertex) * m_vertexCount;
    vbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vbd.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitData;
    vinitData.pSysMem = &(vertices[0]);
    m_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&vbd, &vinitData, &m_pVertexBuffer);

    CreateIndices();

    //Sets terrains Current position in the world to be the top corner
    m_position = verts2d[terrainDimentions - 1][terrainDimentions - 1].Position;

}
```

**Code to Generate Indices**

```
HRESULT TerrainObject::CreateIndices()
{
    UINT faceCount = (terrainDimentions - 1) * (terrainDimentions - 1) * 2; // each quad consists of two triangles


    int index = 0;

    indices.resize(faceCount * 3);
    for (UINT i = 0; i < terrainDimentions - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (UINT j = 0; j < terrainDimentions - 1; ++j)
        {
            indices[index] = i * terrainDimentions + j;
            indices[index + 1] = i * terrainDimentions + j + 1;
            indices[index + 2] = (i + 1) * terrainDimentions + j;

            indices[index + 3] = (i + 1) * terrainDimentions + j;
            indices[index + 4] = i * terrainDimentions + j + 1;
            indices[index + 5] = (i + 1) * terrainDimentions + j + 1;

            index += 6; // next quad
        }
    }



    m_indexCount = indices.size();

    // Creates index buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC ibd;
    ibd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    ibd.ByteWidth = sizeof(WORD) * m_indexCount;
    ibd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    ibd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    ibd.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;
    iinitData.pSysMem = &indices[0];
    return m_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&ibd, &iinitData, &m_pIndexBuffer);

}
```

Comment: I expect it has something to do with this being an integer division:     `float dx = terrainDimentions / (terrainDimentions - 1);`. Try casting terrainDimentions to a float before using it in this expression

Comment: @Tharwen I have added a new float variable called `F_terrainDimentions` and I am using that when calculating floats. Unfortunately it still seems to loop back on itself. Even still its something that could cause issues later down the line so thanks for pointing that out, I will edit the code above with the changes